# Performance for Speaker Identification : Equal Error Rate (EER) and Identification Accuracy

Tags: signal-processing, speech-recognition, speech

I am confused between the metrics used to measure performance of Speaker Identification System (and NOT verification).

Is it Equal Error Rate (EER), Identification Accuracy or both? If both, which is the one of primary importance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone has the same problem, EER is performance metric for Speaker Verification (there are other metrics too like Detection Cost Function (DCF), minDCF, actDCF)

http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/E/equal_error_rate.html

On the other hand, the performance metric for Speaker Identification is Identification Accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

For speaker verification, since it is a type of classification problem. I would use accuracy as well as recall. In fact I think classic, somehow standard, F-meaure would be the best option here.